# Determining the number of distinct p-chains

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Definition: A $p$-chain is a subset of $p$-simplicies in a simplicial complex $K$.

Let $T$ be a tetrahedron - a 3 - simplex. It is trivial to note that the faces of a tetrahedron are 2 - simplex; in this case, the number of 2 - simplex is four.

Indeed, each face of a tetrahedron is a convex hull of some non - empty subset of the $(3+1)$ vertices that defines the 3 - simplex (or tetrahedron) and so each face is a subset of the tetrahedron and so belongs to a simplicial complex.

There are $2^{4}$ distinct 2-chains and $2^{6}$ distinct 1-chains. How do I observe this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting the number of subsets of the set of all subsets of each fixed size.

This will work for the analogues of the tetrahedron in any dimension: the simplicial complex $K_n$ with $n+1$ vertices every subset of which defines a face. For each $p$ there are $\binom{n+1}{p}$ faces of dimension $p$ and
$$
2^\binom{n+1}{p}
$$
$p$-chains.

Comment: "...faces of dimension p+1" or "..faces of dimension p"?

Comment: @Mathematicing Fixed thanks. You could have.